# how to add new application mapping in iis

Tags: windows, iis, vbscript

How can I add new application mapping in IIS using vbscript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Basically you *could* use `adsutil.vbs` to manipulate the ScriptMaps within the MetaBase.

Unfortunately, `adsutil.vbs` is unable to set single items in LIST properties like ScriptMaps. You can only set or delete the list as a whole. Any additional processing would require your own coding.

A person named David Wang has made a VB script that has this capability. He explained in more detail in [his blog entry on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2004/12/02/273681.aspx). The script he made can be copied from there. You can modify other LIST properties with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of ADSI with VBScript. There are several examples here: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/library/IIS/4b976f46-3751-4f6b-ab68-5e19fa73a7b1.mspx