# Adding an extension mapping to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, wmi

if you browse the internet it's relatively easy to find code that modifies existing script maps (to switch between .NET versions, for example).  However, the relatively obvious code to actually add or remove a script map doesn't seem to work.  Has anyone succeeded in writing something that can add or delete a scriptmap in IIS 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:
http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2004/12/02/273681.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look here: [how to add new application mapping in iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265613/how-to-add-new-application-mapping-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

A better answer (that is, one more suitable to my requirements, which were the ability to administration remote machines and use .NET) can be found in a [subseqent Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465548/adding-a-scriptmap-object-using-managementclasses).